# Different Decodings for Union Find

Tags: quantum-algorithms, error-correction

I read a paper about the implementation of a quasilinear UnionFind Decoder for quantum error correction and it says that the last step of it is building a sparse forest and peeling it. My question is the following: since for a given graph there exists multiple sparse trees does that mean that for different implementations of this last step you could get multiple corrections?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

First or all, the order can't matter for a small local cluster. For example, in this diagram, six detection events have merged into one cluster. The two lines represents two observables. No matter how you pair up the six detection events within the cluster, you will always cross the blue line an odd number of times and the red line an even number of times, meaning you get the same prediction.

[image]

The reason you always get the same prediction is because peeling is equivalent to pushing all the detection events to one single point. When detection events cross an observable during this process, they flip it. Different orders correspond to different final points. But you can transform one of them into another by simply sliding the final point around from one to the other. This has no effect on the prediction because that final point contains an even number of excitations. When it crosses an observable it flips that observable an even number of times which is equivalent to not flipping it at all.

The only situations where peeling order *could* matter are situations where the cluster is so large that it contains a topologically non-trivial path or cycle, meaning there are multiple paths a *single* excitation event could take when being pushed to the contraction point. The trouble is that, because growth stops eagerly, this requires some kind of tie breaking scenario. You can't normally create a cluster that contains a path between two boundaries, because as soon as it touches one boundary it stops growing. So it would need to hit them simultaneously. Then, additionally, the growth stage would have to fail to communicate to the peeling stage which paths were actually used to join the cluster together, so that ambiguities in the peeling stage could result in a detection event going to one boundary or the other.

Here's an example without boundaries, on a donut:

[image]

The stars are the detection events. The circles are the flood fill regions that were explored around each event. The gray box is indicating the space wraps around, like a toric code. The black lines are the actual shortest paths along which the flood fill regions collided and were union'd.

The blue circle was the last one to find a partner. As you can tell from the black line, it union'd with the circle to its right. The distance to the circle to its left indicated by the dashed red line happens to be exactly the same, but because of random tie-breaking details in the implementation, that just isn't the path that was used to join the blue circle's detection event into the cluster.

If the peeler has no sense of which shortest paths were used or not used to union the events together, and works purely from the explored area, then it can return different corrections because the explored area contains a topologically non-trivial cycle. For example, if the peeler does its own Djikstra searches, then it might tie-break differently and follow the red dashed line instead of never using it. If that line crosses an observable, that can change the prediction.

If the peeler can only use the paths that were actually used to join clusters, then no matter what order you do things it will always give the same result. For example, if you do [compressed peeling (appending A of the sparse blossom paper)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.15933), then the correction is always identical no matter what order the tree is contracted.

All of this is kind of moot because, if you're in situations where one cluster can contain a topologically non-trivial path or cycle, the qubit is dead. The correction is being chosen by random tie breaking, meaning you're 50/50 sure the qubit contains an error, meaning it is dead.